# Reading input from a file with getline

Tags: c++, file-io, getline

I seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding on file input. I assumed my method would work for a project I am working on, but it simply does not. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   ifstream input;
   char fname[20], lname[20];
   input.open("text.txt");

   input.getline(lname, 20, ',');
   input.getline(fname, 20, ' ');
   cout << lname;
   cout << fname;

}
```

From a file I have:

```
Squarepants, Spongebob
```

and the cout statements do not output anything

What I am doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Assuming the file actually gets opened (I mean you've provided no details to that end, so maybe it didn't), and that the reads succeed, [there is output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa9aa3ae6685a19a).

Comment: Make sure your file is opened successfully. Also, always verify that the read operations are successful.

Comment: @chris  sorry, I was just trying to whip up a snippet of my actual project and did not include error checking just to see if i could get it to work in another context. I still get no output, could it be visual studios?

Comment: All you need is `input.ignore()` after the first getline

Comment: @chris why isnt fname read correctly?

Comment: @user3470987, You told it to read up to the next space. It's at the beginning.

Comment: Either use `input.ignore()`, or get rid of the third argument in the second call to `getline`.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a good pattern to use:

```
std::string lineOfText;

while(fileAccessor.good()) {
    fileAccessor.getline(lineOfText);
    //
    // do stuff
    // do stuff
    //
    if(fileAccessor.eof()) break;
}
```

Comment: Or, remove the individual `good()` and `eof()` checks and just use `while(fileAccessor)` instead. Streams have an [`operator bool()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) that returns `false` when the stream is in `bad`, `fail` or `eof` state.